# Case Sensitive and In-Sensitive search on same field

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

My Schema configuration is shown below

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
 <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="message" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
```

The code goes like

```
if(casesensitive == true)
{
  // do case sensitive search
}
else
{
  // do case in-sensitive search
  http://1.2.3.4/solr/a.b/select?q=message:"hit"
}
```

I am able to do case insensitive search on that field correctly. But if I enter "Hit", I want SOLR to return records matching the same case.

Also I do not want to create a separate field in my Solr, I want to fetch records from same field. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible. You need to add another field if want to achieve both the scenarios.

You need to have 2 fields. One where you will have added the LowerCase Filter factory and for the other don't add.

Using a single field, its not possible. Solr will index the data the way you define the fieldType.

Answer (score 0):

You should use non-stored copy fields:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchCpyFld.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use copyField with store=false and change which field you search against
2. Lower-case on the client.
3. Create [a complex request processor with switch cases](https://gist.github.com/arafalov/5e04884e5aefaf46678c) based on an extra flag (e.g. casesensitive) and do different queries.

If you need to do it for a large number of fields, you can also define an alternative request handler and [redefine aliases](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/languages/conf/solrconfig.xml#L50) for the fields to point to case-sensitive or non-case-sensitive versions.